# Python: If...and... not working as expected

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to set up the below code to ask the user to enter two integers (num_sides & num_rolls). If the user doesn't enter an integer for either input, then the code should print the statement "Enter  an integer".

I find this code only tests the num_sides but doesn't test if num_rolls is an integer. What's going on here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
def rolldice():
    while True:
        while True:
            num_sides = input("Enter number of sides for die: ")
            num_rolls = input("Enter number of rolls for die: ")
            try:
                if int(num_sides) != num_sides or int(num_rolls) != num_rolls:
                    break
                break
            except(ValueError):
                print("Enter an integer")
                True
```

Comment: What an odd loop.  For starters, `num_sides` is being cast to an `int` and being compared to its original form (a string), which will *never* be `True`.

Comment: Why do you have `break`s both inside and outside your `if`? And what did you expect `True` on a line by itself to do for you?

Comment: Some of the answers just test whether they *can be cast* to `int`. Are you also trying to check whether the numbers are integers, or is that not important? I mean, if someone puts in 3.3, do you want it to throw an exception (test whether the number is an *integer*) or just cast to 3 (which is what the current answers do)?

Comment: @leekaiinthesky It wouldn't. If it is Python3 (which seems to be the case) then `input` returns a string and `int('3.3')` would return ValueError. (If OP isn't using Py3, I strongly advise to switch to `raw_input` instead of `input`) The behavior you describe happens when applying `int` to a `float` though, but not its literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have a nested loop? (Two `while True` one inside the other one)

The following code is simpler and should work:

```
def rolldice():
    while True:
        num_sides = input("Enter number of sides for die: ")
        num_rolls = input("Enter number of rolls for die: ")
        try:
            int(num_sides)
            int(num_rolls)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter an integer")
```

If both `int` evaluate and do not crash then `break` is executed and you can leave the loop.

As it is a function, you might want to return `(num_sides, num_rolls)` at the end of the function so they aren't lost. (You could also replace the `break` with the `return`, which will effectively stop the function too at the same time)

Unless this is only the beginning of your code, then never mind what I just said. :)

Comment: Right, there's more to the code...but it wasn't relevant to my question. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast `int` and check for a `ValueError`:

```
def rolldice():
    while True:
        try:
            num_sides = int(input("Enter number of sides for die: "))
            num_rolls = int(input("Enter number of rolls for die: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter an integer")
```

---

```
>>> rolldice()
Enter number of sides for die: 5
Enter number of rolls for die: foo
Enter an integer
Enter number of sides for die: foo 
Enter an integer
Enter number of sides for die: bar
Enter an integer
Enter number of sides for die: 1
Enter number of rolls for die: 2
>>>
```

Comment: Use [```isinstance()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check/confirm the type of an object.

Comment: Shorter than my version. Behaves a bit different than my version, I sticked with OP's format but this is perfectly good too!

Comment: @wwii Not very Pythonic I would say (`is_instance` in general, mainly because of "duck typing").

Comment: @JeromeJ ... I thought I was commenting on an answer that was using ```type``` in a Boolean expression.